# Listen for broadcast event from controller within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that broadcasts an event when some content is loaded like this

```
angular.module('myApp')
  // Using rootScope now
  .controller('SubCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/scripts/data/content.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.content = response.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('dataloaded');
      });
}]);
```

In the matchHeight directive I am listening for the dataloaded event

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('matchHeight', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$on('dataloaded', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          angular.element(element).matchHeight(attrs);
        });
      });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFunction
  };
}]);
```

I am using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage the states
This is the HTML

```
<div class="row usps">
  <div class="col-sm-4 usp-block" ng-repeat="block in content.marketing" match-height>
    // Inner HTML
  </div>
</div>
```

The broadcast event is not picked up from within the directive. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that `content.marketing` contains data and  `scope.$on` get executed before `.$broadcast`. Put log and check execution order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the fact that you are inside `ngRepeat`, contents will get rendered only after the broadcast triggers, so directive will. Then your directive link will only subscribe to the event but it won't execute, because it had already been executed before that `ngRepeat` finishes rendering your directive.

In order to fix this, by the fact that `ngRepeat` will recreate your list every time you change the array, directive will always be reconstructed when necesssary so you don't have to listen to an event.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('matchHeight', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(element).matchHeight(attrs);
      });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFunction
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I have tried to use $rootScope. But it still is not reaching the directive scope. I will edit my question so you can see what I changed

Comment: @Gert-JanKooijmans sorry, wasn't finished yet, I made some tests and figured what is happening. Updated my answer